# Cannot connect to remote mongodb server

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, linode

I changed bindIp setting to

> bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0

in mongod.conf on my ubuntu server hosted on Linode and restarted mongod and status looks ok.

I opened mongodb port on ufw

sudo ufw status
Status: active

> To                         Action      From
>   --                         ------      ---- 22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                   10000
>   ALLOW       Anywhere                   Nginx Full
>   ALLOW       Anywhere                   3333
>   ALLOW       Anywhere                   27017
>   ALLOW       Anywhere                   22/tcp (v6)
>   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              10000 (v6)
>   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              Nginx Full (v6)
>   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              3333 (v6)
>   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              27017 (v6)
>   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Connecting to it from my mac throws error:

> mongo mongodb://admin:secret@ubuntuipaddress/fielddb?authSource=admin
>   MongoDB shell version v3.6.2 connecting to:
>   mongodb://ubuntuipaddress/fielddb?authSource=admin
>   2018-04-08T13:47:32.212 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to
>   ubuntuipaddress:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll),
>   reason: Connection refused 2018-04-08T13:47:32.214 E QUERY
>   [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server ubuntuipaddress:27017,
>   connection attempt failed : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
>   @(connect):1:6 exception: connect failed

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you `telnet ubuntuipaddress 27017` from your Mac?

Comment: telnet to 27017 I get connection refused error but telnet to 3333 works fine

Comment: Not too sure what's running on `3333`. But, try running `sudo ufw allow 27017/tcp`?

Comment: I tried sudo ufw allow 27017/tcp and confirm that this change was made but it did not make any dfference

Comment: Can you change the public port that MongoDB listens on to something else?

Comment: Also could you past the `ufw-user-input` from the `iptables --list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was wrong setting of bindIP in mmongod.conf. Changing to:

> bindIp: 127.0.0.1,ip_address_of_host_running_mondgod

fixed the problem. Replace ip_address_of_host_running_mondgod
 with ip address of host running mongod like 137.142.177.4

Answer (score 2):

The basic steps for enabling remote access for Mongodb running on Ubuntu are:

1. Setup a minimum of one user in Mongodb (admin with root rights)
2. Edit the config file (i.e. sudo nano etc/mongodb.conf)
3. Make sure that

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0 
port = 27017 
auth = true
```

are set (and uncommented)

3. Add a firewall rule in UFW to allow 27017 from your remote IP address (or anywhere)

You should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Disable your firewall and try to see if you can connect, if you can then it's your fw rules. Try this first to see if this helps.

Comment: I did sudo ufw disable  but same problem -- connection to 2701 refused. I verfied mongod is running and am able to run apps local to mongodb on linode vps  and they can access and write data without problem.

Comment: same here... runs in local, cannot remote connect