# Can not connect to remote database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

Local config: 
Node.js 12.2.0

Server config:
VPS
Ubuntu 18.04
MongoDB 3.2.22

There is basic script to connect to remote mongodb database. This returns error -  `Cannot read property 'db' of null.`

There are `admin` and `test` databases.
For admin DB I created an user

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "root",
    pwd: "passw0rd",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

node app.js

```
// app.js

const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

// const url = "mongodb://root:passw0rd@46.173.213.195:27017/admin";
const url = "mongodb://46.173.213.195:27017/test";
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });

mongoClient.connect(function(err, client){      
    const db = client.db("admin");
    const collection = db.collection("users");
    let user = {name: "Tomy", age: 23};
    collection.insertOne(user, function(err, result){        
        if(err){ 
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(result.ops);
        client.close();
    });
});
```

```
// package.json

{
   "name": "mongoapp",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "dependencies": {
      "express": "^4.16.0",
      "body-parser": "^1.18.0",
      "mongodb": "^3.1.0"
   }
}
```

Both urls returns errors.

What I tried:

1. Changed bindIp to any

```
///nano etc/mongod.conf

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

2. sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN

```
tcp    0    0 0.0.0.0:27017      0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      17184/mongod
...
...
```

3. Applied this code for iptables

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 185.228.232.150 -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 185.228.232.150 -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

4. `sudo systemctl status mongodb` tells that db works good

Can anyone help?.. 
The code can be tested from your computer.

Update:
Accoringly to that post https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-bind-failed-errno99-cannot-assign-requested-address-for-socket/ bindIp shouldn't be equals to server IP.

Comment: Are you able to connect via command line?

Comment: I didn't plan to use mongo shell to work with database. Can not use command line yet.

Comment: I found solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716190/cannot-connect-to-remote-mongodb-server?rq=1 The question left is why mongo refuses to start working with this IP

Answer (score 0):

Your DB is running well and so does application. Problem is in application to DB network communication. Please check for the below points (assuming your DB is running on 46.173.213.195)

1. DB host: Check if necessary inbound rules are defined properly in your remote database host. That mean DB host is allowing port 27017 from application IP etc.
2. DB host: Change Bind ip to 46.173.213.195
3. Application host: Telnet 46.173.213.195:27017.

Now if your telnet is successful, application should be able to communicate remote DB too.

Comment: 1. Do you mean mongod.conf ? I showed config above.
2. Thanks for advice. It's strange that when I point 46.173.213.195 for Bind ip  - I can not start my database working. Yaml config file doesn't have type errors.

Comment: One more notice - firewall is inactive

Comment: (1). Inbound rules are for machines/hosts not DB
(2). If you have bind IP anything else than localhost, you need to add --host={your_bind_ip} toggle while starting mongo

Comment: Why should I point host? This uri has my IP address already:

`const url = "mongodb://46.173.213.195:27017/test"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how - it just started working. 
bindIp: 0.0.0.0

I think, after a bunch of reloads and config updating